# CSS - Position flex siblings next to eachother

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building my first html page for a personal web app I'm working on. The page has a navbar positioned on the side using the  tag. I am trying to position the content of the page beside the navbar, but the content is not showing. My code is shown below. I was told to use flex-inline to position the navbar and content next to each other, but it still doesn't work. Only the navbar shows. If I comment out the `<header>` and add `float: right` to `#dashboard-content`, the content shows in the correct position. I just can't get both the navbar and the content to show, correctly, at the same time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
* {
    font-family: Verdana, Georgia, sans-serif;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: #121212;
}

/*====================       Navbar       ====================*/
.navbar {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
}

.navbar-btn {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #292929;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-color: #292929;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9966CC;
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-color: #9966CC;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.navbar-btn:active {
    background-color: #9966CC;
    border-color: #9966CC;
    color: #1f1f1f;
}

/*====================     Dashboard      ====================*/
#dashboard-content {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/fontawesome/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="navbar">
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">New Transaction</a>
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">Transactions</a>
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">Settings</a>
    </header>
    <main id="dashboard-content">
        
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put all of them into a `div` tag and use `display: flex` on the `div`

something like this

```css
* {
    font-family: Verdana, Georgia, sans-serif;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: #121212;
}
div{
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
  display:flex;
}
/*====================       Navbar       ====================*/
.navbar {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
}

.navbar-btn {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #292929;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-color: #292929;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9966CC;
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-color: #9966CC;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.navbar-btn:active {
    background-color: #9966CC;
    border-color: #9966CC;
    color: #1f1f1f;
}

/*====================     Dashboard      ====================*/
#dashboard-content {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/fontawesome/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <header class="navbar">
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">New Transaction</a>
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">Transactions</a>
        <a href="" class="navbar-btn">Settings</a>
    </header>
    <main id="dashboard-content">
        
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create wrapping parent block for header and main with `display: flex`. Also no need to use in #dashboard-content

```
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

flex-direction with value row works as default in flex element.
Furthermore, apply `flex-shrink: 0`; for header to prevent compression of left block.